# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error when making a request to a public API

Tags: api, cors, xmlhttprequest

This is [the documentation](https://kiwi-coin.com/help.html#!/api-description/) of the API I'm trying to make a request to.
Relevant section:

> ## Public Data Functions
>
> ### Ticker
>
> `GET https://kiwi-coin.com/api/ticker/`
>
> Returns JSON object:
>
> - last - last BTC price
> - date - price date
> - high - last 24 hours till date price high
> - low - last 24 hours till date price low
> - vwap - last 24 hours till date volume weighted average price: vwap
> - volume - last 24 hours till date volume
> - bid - highest buy order
> - ask - lowest sell order

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://kiwi-coin.com/api/ticker/",
});
```

<sup><sub>Yep, there's no way of handling the response. Ignore this for now,
 I'm just focusing on getting the request to work.</sub></sup>

Here's the error I get in the console:

> Failed to load https://kiwi-coin.com/api/ticker/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://cloud-rooster.glitch.me' is therefore not allowed access.

What am I doing wrong? This API works for other users (e.g. bots).

I checked out the other questions with a similar title, but from what I could make out the answers all involved making changes to the server, which isn't an option in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was running the function from the client-side (in the browser), rather than server-side (in a Node.js environment).

Duh!

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the API server doesn't support CORS, there are two options:

1. `JSONP`. Though you can't make cross-origin XHRs without adequate permission, you CAN include a JavaScript file from anywhere. If the API server returns something like `callback({ json data ...})`, then you can use the data without having to jump through hoops. However, it doesn't seem like KiwiCoin supports that.
2. Run your own server from the same origin as your client application (probably the same server that hosts your HTML/JS files), and have endpoints on your server that forward to the API server. This is foolproof.

One thing I noticed from looking at your code is that you have calls to `process.env`, which doesn't exist in the browser. That might be the sign you need to try option #2!

Comment: `process.env` is specifically for the Glitch environment :) it doesn't work in the client side code, I just put the details in there to keep them private.